# Where to initialize GPS to stay on for longer than the activities

Tags: android, gps

I am writing an application that has to send to the server its GPS location every X seconds, and I was wondering if the right place to have this running was inside the Application Class since it has to keep sending messages even if you change activities.

Right now I initialized inside the activity and then have a different thread with a timer send the latest location to the backend.

Am I correct? I ask mainly because I have had complains that the GPS sometimes gets stuck, but when they launch another application with a GPS it starts working again in my program.

[EDIT: the application is for a company that will be using the app alone in a Galaxy Tab]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way: Create a Service and register it to listen to LocationManager updates. If you want to send data even when phone goes to sleep then take a look at WAKE LOCK.

However this will use GPS and network and will drain battery. People don't like such apps - I know I wouldn't use it.

To make things more user-friendly:

1. Use passive location provider. This leeches location data when other apps use Gps. Use Gps directly only when you dont get data for a longer period.
2. Cache location data. Register with sync manager to update data when other app also update data. Use DownloadManager to upload data files: DM is smart, it automatically retries on error, even if device is restarted. If files are big, then set it to only upload over wifi.

I highly recommend watching Reto Meier's Android Protips video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=twmuBbC_oB8